# Convert integer to string

Tags: php

I have a variable storing value separated by comma

```
$integers = 1,5,8,4,3;
```

I need To make every value like

```
$finalvalue = '1','5','8','4','3'
```

Comment: Those aren't valid PHP. Please show your valid code / data.

Comment: Did you read the PHP reference manual?  There's well documented methods for both dealing with comma separated strings and with type conversion.

Comment: @JonStirling i have not written any code. i need to the value like this '1','2','3','4','5'

Comment: So you can do `$value="'1','2','3','4','5'";`

Comment: @Dev Then at least make your pseudo code valid. What is the _actual_ input? What output are you actually wanting?

Comment: @JonStirling I am getting value from loop like __1,5,8,4,3__ and then i want to convert it to __'1','5','8','4','3'__

Comment: look up array_map in the PHP manual

Comment: *sigh*. is `1,5,8,4,3` a string, or an array. Are you wanting to convert it to the string `'1','5','8','4','3'`, or an array containing `1`, `5`, `8`, `4`, `3`,

Comment: @JonStirling __1,5,8,4,9__ is a string and i wanting it to the string __'1','5','8','4','3'__

Comment: @Dev Okay, so `explode` the string on `,`, `array_walk` the array to add the quotes, then `implode` the array back to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $integers = '1,5,8,4,3';  //Convert into String
    $arr = explode(',', $integers); // String to Array Conversation

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $val[] = "'".$value."'"; // add your requirements here
    }

    $finalvalue = implode(',', $val); // Array to string 
    echo $finalvalue;   // your final result
?>
```